# Как не терять результат при рекурсии?

Tags: javascript

**Задача:** написать функцию, которая рекурсивно будет убирать вложенные подмассивы. *(Аналог Array.prototype.flat)*

Я написал следующий код:

```
const result = [];

function flat(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            return flat(array[i]);
        } else {
            result.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9], 10]];

console.log(flat(array));
```

Он работает, но мне нужно поместить `const result = []` в саму функцию. Соответственно, если я его помещаю в нее с данной реализацией, рекурсия его каждый раз обновляет.

**Какой наиболее элегантный выход из этого положения?**

Comment: либо передавать параметром, либо возвращать в качестве результата

Comment: кроме того, текущая реализация вернет неверный результат, если вложенный массив будет не последним элементом.

Comment: да, тоже заметил, но почему? после обработки вложенного массива же должен быть еще один индекс по которому он пройдет, поймет, что это не массив и запушит в результирующий массив

Comment: да, передав параметром все стало как надо, но пока не понимаю как избавиться от вышеупомянутой проблемы

Answer (score 2):

Передавайте result просто как параметр:

```js
function flat(array, result=[]) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
             flat(array[i] , result);
        } else {
            result.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9], 10],11];

console.log(flat(array));
```

> да, передав параметром все стало как надо, но пока не понимаю как
> избавиться от вышеупомянутой проблемы

а проблема была в том, что после return совершается выход из всех функций сразу, просто надо убрать 'return'

Answer (score 1):

Пример реализации без мутирования аргументов:

```js
function flat(array) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
        result = result.concat(flat(array[i])); // Объединяем массив с подмассивами
    } else {
        result.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const array = [1, [2, 3, [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9]]], 10];

console.log(flat(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы убрать первый уровень вложенности, можно воспользоваться методом [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), например

```
[].concat(...array);
```

Чтобы применить ко всем уровням, нужно применить функцию для каждого элемента из `array` и результат передать в `concat`.

для этого можно воспользоваться методом [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
[].concat(...array.map(flat));
```

Осталось добавить ограничение  рекурсии: в случае когда передали не массив - нужно вернуть сам элемент

```
if (!Array.isArray(array)) return array;
```

В итоге можно получить следующее:

```js
function flat(array) {
  if (!Array.isArray(array)) return array;

  return [].concat(...array.map(flat))
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9], 10], 11];

console.log(flat(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Просто передайте результирующий массив вторым аргументом.**

*+ Доработан алгоритм. Тот что в условии - неправильный.*

```js
function flat(array, res = []) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            flat(array[i], res);
        }
        else {
            res.push(array[i])
        };
    }
    return res;
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], 7, 10, [1, 2, 3, [0],
  [10, 99, [90], 2]
]];

console.log(flat(array));
```

Comment: зачем делать `delete array[i]` если можно просто `else` поставить?

Comment: обрати внимание, что у тебя элемент `0` исчез

Comment: Аааа, спасибо. не учел, что 0 тоже к false приводится

Answer (score 0):

Можете просто обернуть рекурсивную функцию во внешней функции, которую вызываете:

```
function flat(array)
    {
    const result = [];
    function inner(array) {
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
                inner(array[i]);
            } else {
                result.push(array[i]);
            }
        }
        }
        inner(array);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: та же самая проблема с не последним вложенным массивом, что и в исходном коде

Comment: я про сам алгоритм не знаю правильный он или нет, я про то что, если ему надо сохранить переменную рекурсивной функции, то проще обернуть вызовы рекурсии во внешней функции, в которой переменные определить.

Comment: да там просто надо убрать return вроде